AMD Radeon RX 7700S is not recognized by any GPU backend of Blender

This computer has a Radeon RX 7700S and is running up-to-date Ubuntu 24.04 LTS.
This issue occurs when installing Blender from the App Center as a snap and when downloading from the website.

This thread suggest using the flatpak version. I'm skeptical, but trying it anyway
